# Parsing and getting data from incoming google maps share (intent)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I have been encountering the following problem:
Whenever I get an intent from google maps, the format I receive the information in is looking like this : "https://maps.app.goo.gl/XfxhHUSwTiSKSQBv7" (for example).
when I manually reach for the link, it goes through two redirections.
only the second one has the lat and lng in the url and the first one doesnt.
I dont need the URL's necessarily, but I do need to extract the lat and lng somehow.
I would appreciate any help in the matter.
Thanks

P.s. If there's a solution that doesnt require using token-required api's, id rather that.

I tried getting the "Location" header field but it only gets me to the first redirection, that doesnt contain the necessary information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe it is done in that way since you're nnot supposed to get data from an intent and use the APIs instead.